# Deserialzing JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, nullreferenceexception, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON in C# but I'm getting NullReferenceException and I don't know why.

Here is the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
{"Entries": {"Entry": {"day": "28","month": "10","year": "1955","type": "birthday","title": "Bill Gates was born!","picture": "","video": ""}}}
```

and I'm using this code

```
public class Entry
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string video { get; set; }
}

public class Entries
{
    public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
}

private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json = new StreamReader("events.json").ReadToEnd();
    var entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entries>(json);
    MessageBox.Show(entries.entry[0].day); // NullReferenceException
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

and when I change the JSON to

```
{"Entries": ["Entry": {"day": "28","month": "10","year": "1955","type": "birthday","title": "Bill Gates was born!","picture": "","video": ""}]}
```

I get `After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :. Path 'Entries[0]', line 1, position 20.`

**EDIT**

I played with the JSON and the one bellow worked for me:

```
[{"day": "28","month": "10","year": "1955","type": "birthday","title": "Bill Gates was born!","picture": "","video": ""}]
```

Comment: Attach a debugger. Inspect the actual deserialized data. Anyway, the problem is *there is no array* in the JSON.

Comment: The debugger says that entries is null and I don't see why.

Comment: ".. the problem is *there is no array* in the JSON". The deserializer requires an array to be able to populate `List<Entry> entry`. Trust the deserializer - if it doesn't populate a field correctly, then the source data probably didn't align. (Also, some names - e.g. Entry vs entry - are incorrect.)

Comment: As for the new error, well, that is because *it is invalid JSON*. Again, *trust the deserializer*. A breakup would go like this: "No, it's you .. really." - compare with: `{"Entries": [{day: ..}, {day: ..}]}` where `{day: ..}` represents a particular `Entry` object when deserialized.

Comment: Could you just post the whole JSON of the above examples, because I just started using it today. Thanks!

Comment: Running the second JSON entry in your post through any validator shows it invalid.  I'd be willing to bet it's your `[ ]` brackets.

Comment: @Evanlewis, cold you post a valid one for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Glad you solved your problem - remember, trust the tools (or have good reason to challenge them)!

Answer (score 1):

Your json is correct, if you should change the class definitions as follows, then this will work

(BTW: you may find [this site](http://json2csharp.com/) useful)

```
var entries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

---

```
public class Entry
{
    public string day { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string video { get; set; }
}

public class Entries
{
    public Entry Entry { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Entries Entries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that didn't work for me. The guy above told me that my JSON is incorrect (check the updated version). I need the class Entries to have an array of classes Entry.